# iOS SDK 11 error when using PhoneGap Build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap, iphone-x

When submitting an app to the app store I get the following error from Apple:

`The app previews and screenshots for the iPhone 5.8-Inch display won’t appear on the App Store because your binary wasn’t built with the iOS 11 SDK.`

It's a normal app compiled with PhoneGap Build. Anyone know why this is happening? Is it because PhoneGap Build does not use iOS 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap Build does support iOS 11 (I just had an app approved a week ago). I'm not sure exactly what would cause this, but here's a few things to check that I recently updated to:

- Use the latest version of PG Build, which will support iOS 11 (my best guess for the cause of your issue):

  < preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
- If that doesn't fix it, switch over to the [CLI project structure](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/getting-started/app-project-structure/) format.

Comment: I thought this would fix it but it doesn't. It appears it's because the PhoneGap Build still uses XCode 8 instead of 9.

Comment: Ah, OK.  PhoneGap Build does lag a bit behind the Cordova CLI tools, so this makes sense.

Comment: @MikeM, did you find a solution for this? also, does that mean your app will get rejected? I have submitted my app for review and waiting for the review decision but I got that error as well in the itunes connect!

Comment: @DavidHope I don't think the app will get rejected. It's just a warning. I've heard from other people who has their app approved.